# The best memory configuration for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one linux server with 128G memory and 32 cpu cores. I would run an ElasticSearch instance on this server, the server is exclusively only for running ES. So how many memory I should configure for ES. How could I get the best performance of ES please. Is the server too luxurious for ES? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe run a VM hypervisor or docker containers on that maschine to host a ES cluster? Better build a cluster that one giant instance - ES was made to be run distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you run two ES instances in each server. Since your linux server pretty powerful, if you set the ES memory as 60g or 80g it may encounter GC problem. Try to run two or three ES instances in one server and monitor the CPU and Memory usage, btw, change the http port of ES for running multiple nodes in one server.

Comment: Running multiple ES nodes on the same machine to benefit of all the available memory is one point, but if your physical machine goes down your cluster will be down. Or worse if the HDD of that single machine gets corrupted for some reason, you'll loose all your data.

Comment: Thanks Val, your suggestions make sense. In reality I run two ES instances in one server for better parallel computation, because I found my server cpu always keep 8% usage, I think the best cpu usage should be higher. i.e I'm wasting the hardware resource if I can not make cpu usage higher. And, per my experience the best maximum of ES memory should be around 30g. but in reality my each server has 150g memory so I ran two ES simultaneously. I set replicate is 3, so if one server down should be ok.

Comment: 30.5GB is the highest you should go. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops